# Laining with Less than 10 Men?

Tags: tefilla, torah-reading, minyan

A nursing home in an out of town community, for example, may not get 10 men each shabbos for laining. It is clear from Shulchan Aruch (143:1) that you need 10 men, and I have yet to see other authorities who are lenient in a less than ideal situation.

Has anyone heard of a source that may allow laining with less than 10, as an emergency situation?

Comment: b'dieved means after the fact - if you want to plan ahead to have less than 10 men, it cannot mean b'dieved. That would be if you discovered, after the fact, that one of the 10 men is not Jewish, and asked if the laining was still valid.

Comment: Reading the Torah is an obligation on a tzibbur; not individuals. Without a minyan, the obligation doesn't even start.

Comment: And [welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yaakov. 

Hope to see you around!

Comment: Why is this voted as practical psak? I see nothing in the question that indicates that this is a practical question. However, if it is, I recommend that you see the [faq page](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi) explaining why such questions are discouraged.

Comment: I recall hearing something about 9 men and a boy holding a sefer torah (or even 9 men and a sefer torah?) Or, like the shul in Chevron, just invite Avraham Avinu.

Comment: @mbloch - I understand your point; I mean b'dieved in the sense that it is a dochak situation; we will have only 9 men and it would be nice to lain. But, yes, I realize that it probably can't happen.

Comment: @mevaqesh Good point. I hear ya.

Comment: @danielF - obviously I won't pasken based on these responses; I just wanted to hear if anyone knew of a source I could examine that allowed it in a dochak situation. If anyone is interested, I did find the following link which claims to come up with a solution of reading without making brachos. https://dinonline.org/2012/09/05/reading-from-torah-without-minyan/

Comment: Find a yeshiva student to come along and make the minyan.

Comment: @mevaqesh it might still be nice for the older people to be able to follow the weekly parshiyot even if they may not be with it enough to do shnayim mikra anymore.  Even without a chiyuv, I think that's what I would want if at age 119 I'm in such a position.  To accomplish that you could just have someone read from a Chumash though.

Answer (score 1):

[Megila 23b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9660&st=&pgnum=46&hilite=) says that Kriyas HaTorah requires a Minyan. Meiri explains since we say Borchu and Borchu can only be recited with a Minyan.

Levush says that since Kriyas HaTorah is a Davar Shebekedusha דבר שבקדושה it requires a Minyan as the Posuk says ונקדשתי בתוך בני ישראל.

[Rambam Tefila 12:3](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2212.htm) says a Minyan is required for Kriyas HaTorah.

[Yerushalmi Megila 4:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47657&st=&pgnum=144&hilite=) says a Minyan is required to start Kriyas HaTorah. However if it began and people left it may continue even if there is less than a Minyan remaining.

Thanks to [הלכה - דיני קריאת התורה from Rabbi Naftali Hoffner](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43399&st=&pgnum=20) for the sources in this answer.

It seems like the consensus is that Kriyas HaTorah requires a Minyan.